# js to php by json

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

Отправляю json на php следующим образом:

```
$.getJSON('json.php', '{"var_name" : "var_value"}',function(data){...
```

На php получаю через `$_GET`, но он пуст. Как правильно принять json?

Comment: Так это через ajax надо

Comment: не обязательно через ajax

Comment: а случаем не на вордпрессе это все происходит?

Answer (score 1):

Кавычки у вас лишние. Если вы хотите послать объект чтобы тот пришел в `$_GET`, то следует посылать его как объект, а не как строку:

```
$.getJSON('json.php', {"var_name" : "var_value"}, function(data){...
                  /* ^^^  нет кавычек           ^^^ */
```

Comment: `следует посылать его как объект, а не как строку` - как раз наоборот..............я бы не советовал посылать как объект, ибо если переменных будет достаточно много - то сервер PHP может подавиться и выбросить ошибку, в случае если в настройках не поставлено корректное значение `max_input_vars`. Лучше пользоваться `JSON.stringify`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский добавьте свой ответ